# useEffect not displaying async function result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a pretty straightforward example and after reading several other StackOverflow posts, I thought this would work just fine. Evidently, it does not. I am getting `data > Promise {<pending>}` in my log despite `console.logs()` written *inside* the async function's body return the desired value.

***async function***

```
const firestoreGetTopics = async (onlyTitles?: boolean) => {
  try {
    const snapshot = await firebaseFirestore.collection("topics").get();
    if (onlyTitles) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().title);
    }
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error fetching Topics: ", error);
  }
};
```

***component with useEffect***

```
const FileUpload = ({ dispatch }: Props) => {

 ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = firestoreGetTopics();
    console.log("data", data);           <-- logs "data > Promise {<pending>}"
  }, []);

 ...

}
```

Going to keep digging around, though the example I have *matches* other similar solutions I've found here ... so I'm a bit confused by this. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `fireshoreGetTopics` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so in order to get the actual result of your function you either need to use `await` keyword or get the result by using `then` method on the Promise:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async function(){
    const data = await firestoreGetTopics();
    console.log("data", data)
  })()
}, []);
```

or with promise syntax:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  firestoreGetTopics().then(data => {
    console.log("data", data);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: interesting alternative ways of resolving it. The `then` approach is a pretty interesting solution that looks pretty clean all things considered.

Answer (score 3):

The function `firestoreGetTopics` is **asynchronous**, so you need to `await` that.

Try as the following with `await` within an `async` function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const run = async () => {
       const data = await firestoreGetTopics();
       console.log("data", data);           
    }

    run();
}, []);
```

Comment: Great, that worked. Thanks! Now I need to figure out how to make my typescript `useState` patiently await that array of topics.